Which of the ContourPlots is correct?
I'd like to visualize the solution of the system
Reduce[Log[3, a - x^2] == Log[3, a - y^2] && 
x^2 + x^2 == 4 x + 6 y, {x, y}, Reals]


((a > 25 && x == 5) || (a > 0 && x == 0) || (a > 1 && x == -1)) &&  y == 1/3 (-2 x + x^2)

in 14.0 on Windows 10.
Let us consider
a = 3/4; ContourPlot[{Log[3, a - x^2] == Log[3, a - y^2], 
x^2 + x^2 == 4 x + 6 y}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, PlotPoints -> 50]


It seems that the domains of the logarithms over the reals are not taken into account in view of
Log[3, a - x^2] /. {a -> 3/4, x -> -1, y -> 1}


(I \[Pi] - Log[4])/Log[3]

If we take these domains into account, then the result of
ContourPlot[{Log[3, a - x^2] == Log[3, a - y^2], x^2 + x^2 == 4 x + 6 y}, 
{x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, PlotPoints -> 50, RegionFunction -> 
Function[{x, y},  Evaluate[FunctionDomain[Log[3, a - x^2], x] && 
FunctionDomain[Log[3, a - y^2], y]]]]


differs.
The question arises: which of these plots should we consider to be correct?

This doesn't make any sense. The only solution to your equation for $a=3/4$ is $(x,y)=(0,0)$: a = 3/4; Reduce[Log[3, a - x^2] == Log[3, a - y^2] && x^2 + x^2 == 4  x + 6  y, {x, y}, Reals] You should not be plotting two separate countour lines (blue and yellow), but only one: ContourPlot[{Log[3, a - x^2] == Log[3, a - y^2] && x^2 + x^2 == 4  x + 6  y}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}].

@Domen: Thank you for the interest to  the question. Sorry, your "This doesn't make any sense" is not grounded. See Wiki for such type visualization. I will be waiting for serious replies.

What is incorrect in my question? To down vote without any explanation is unfair.

@Domen: Also see the Applications section  in the documentation.

It seems  Mathematica math sometimes is not traditional.

I'd like to quote the Details and Options section from the documentation "At positions where f does not evaluate to a real number, holes are left so that the background to the contour plot shows through"

Plot of Log[3, a - x^2] == Log[3, a - y^2] will evaluate to True or False, not a real or complex number. Contour is where it is True. The doc to which you refer applies for Log[3, a - x^2] - Log[3, a - y^2] which shows holes for complex difference. As Domen points out, both plots are correct given what you specified. The first plot is for all real {x, y} in the plot range, the second is restricted to only  real {x, y} for which the logs are also real.

Both plots are correct. The first one is correct in a more general sense, where $\log : \mathbb C \setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb C$:
a = 3/4;
Reduce[Log[3, a - x^2] == Log[3, a - y^2] && x^2 + x^2 == 4  x + 6  y, {x, y}]
(* (x == -1 || x == 0 || x == 5) && y == 1/3 (-2 x + x^2) *)

while the second one is correct if you are limiting yourself only to $\log : \mathbb R^+ \to \mathbb R$:
a = 3/4;
Reduce[Log[3, a - x^2] == Log[3, a - y^2] && x^2 + x^2 == 4  x + 6  y, {x, y}, Reals]
(* x == 0 && y == 0 *)


Sorry, your claim "Both plots are correct" is built on the sand. Your solve the system for a==3/4 over the reals and complexes. This is not related to ContourPlot at all. I'd like to quote the Details and Options section from  the documentation  "At positions where f does not evaluate to a real number, holes are left so that the background to the contour plot shows through"

@user64494, there are two distinct use cases of ContourPlot. The first one is plotting the contours of a function, ContourPlot[f]. This is the case for which your quote applies, for example ContourPlot[Log[x], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}] has a "hole" at the left side. But the second use case where you have an equation ContourPlot[f == g] is different, and you can obviously see that your comment does not apply to this use case: ContourPlot[Log[x] == Log[y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]. Which is completely logical, as you cannot really say what is f or g in an equation, right?

I'd like to quote the previous part  "When given equations f==g, ContourPlot shows the curves of {x,y} that satisfy the equation. No shading of regions is done; the curves from multiple equations can intersect each other in arbitrary ways for which shading is meaningless. It visualizes the set ${ (x,y) |   f(x,y)=g(x,y} \wedge (x,y) \in reg  }$". The resukt of ContourPlot[Log[x] == Log[y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}] contradicts usual covensions of traditional math. I am sure that result is a bug in ContourPlot.

Please pay your attention to the result of ContourPlot[{Re[Log[x]] == Re[Log[y]],    Im[Log[x]] == Im[Log[y]]}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotPoints -> 50].

It doesn't contradict anything, and it is not a bug. $\log x = \log y$ is perfectly satisfied for $x=y=-1$. As for your last example: You should pay attention to what the function is meant for. ContourPlot[f==g] will not plot a region, that is why you only see the border lines. Compare with RegionPlot[{Re[Log[x]] == Re[Log[y]], Im[Log[x]] == Im[Log[y]]}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]

You are partly right. Unfortunately, ContourPlot[  Re[Log[x]] == Re[Log[y]] && Im[Log[x]] == Im[Log[y]], {x, -2,    2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotPoints -> 50] produces empty plot to me.

It's an empty plot because you are not using the function correctly. You cannot use boolean predicates in ContourPlot! Just read the documentation and don't make things up ...

Thank you. You are right, but isn't it a deficiency of ContourPlot? Also why  do ContourPlot[f[x,y]] and ContourPlot[f[x,y]==g[x,y]] differently handle complex values of  functions ? As we see, this is not convenient when visualizing solutions of some systems of equations over the reals.

$Version

"14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)"

Clear["Global`*"]

Specifying the domain in Reduce is overly restrictive. As stated in the documentation, "If dom is Reals, or a subset such as Integers or Rationals, then all constants and function values are also restricted to be real."
sol1 = Reduce[
  Log[3, a - x^2] == Log[3, a - y^2] && x^2 + x^2 == 4  x + 6  y, {x, y}, 
  Reals]

(* ((a > 25 && x == 5) || (a > 0 && x == 0) || (a > 1 && x == -1)) && 
 y == 1/3 (-2 x + x^2) *)

For a == 3/4 this gives a single point
Solve[sol1 /. a -> 3/4, {x, y}]

(* {{x -> 0, y -> 0}} *)

Compare with just specifying that x and y are real.
sol2 = Assuming[{x, y} ∈ Reals,
  Reduce[Log[3, a - x^2] == Log[3, a - y^2] && x^2 + x^2 == 4  x + 6  y, {x, 
     y}] // Simplify]

(* ((a != 1 && x == -1) || (a != 0 && x == 0) || (a != 25 && x == 5)) && 
 x^2 == 2 x + 3 y *)

sol2 /. a -> 3/4

(* (x == -1 || x == 0 || x == 5) && x^2 == 2 x + 3 y *)

For a == 3/4 this gives all three points.
pts = {x, y} /. Solve[sol2 /. a -> 3/4, {x, y}]

(* {{-1, 1}, {0, 0}, {5, 5}} *)

With[{a = 3/4}, 
 ContourPlot[{Log[3, a - x^2] == Log[3, a - y^2], 
   x^2 + x^2 == 4  x + 6  y}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, PlotPoints -> 50,
  Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[6], Point[pts]},
  PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05]]]


EDIT: In Log[3, a - x^2] == Log[3, a - y^2] the two logs don't have to be real for the logs to be equal. The first ContourPlot is correctly showing all of the real values of {x, y} for which the logs are equal including when the logs are complex.
Log[3, a - x^2] == Log[3, a - y^2] /. y -> x

(* True *)

{Log[3, a - x^2] , Log[3, a - y^2]} /. a -> 3/4 /. {x -> -2., y -> -2.}

(* {1.07286 + 2.8596 I, 1.07286 + 2.8596 I} *)

Equal @@ %

(* True *)


Thank you for  an elaboration of the topic. Sorry, all that is aside. You don't answer "Which of these plots should we consider to be correct?".  Also your "Specifying the domain in Reduce is overly restrictive" contradicts usual conventions of traditional math. I will be waiting for serious answers.

In fact, the assumptions {x, y} ∈ Reals do nothing. Compare with ClearAll[x,y,a]; Reduce[  Log[3, a - x^2] == Log[3, a - y^2] && x^2 + x^2 == 4  x + 6  y, {x,    y}] which results in ((-1 + a != 0 && x == -1) || (a != 0 && x == 0) || (-25 + a != 0 &&       x == 5)) && y == 1/3 (-2 x + x^2).

While the assumption does not affect the result, it is the manner in which the variables are restricted to being real without also requiring that "all constants and function values are also restricted to be real."

BobHanlon (@does not work): I repeat  all that is aside. You don't answer "Which of these plots should we consider to be correct?".

I'd like to quote the Details and Options section from the documentation  "At positions where f does not evaluate to a real number, holes are left so that the background to the contour plot shows through"

Plot of Log[3, a - x^2] == Log[3, a - y^2] will evaluate to True or False, not a real or complex number. Contour is where it is True. The doc to which you refer applies for Log[3, a - x^2] - Log[3, a - y^2] which shows holes for complex difference. As Domen points out, both plots are correct given what you specified. The first plot is for all real {x, y} in the plot range, the second is restricted to only  real {x, y} for which the logs are also real. I inferred that you were questioning whether the first plot was correct and stated "first ContourPlot is correctly showing ..."

BobHanlon (@does not work): In traditional math only  "real {x, y} for which the logs are also real" are taken into account. So Mathematica math is not traditional in the case under consideration.
